# Form ui fieldset load data

Tags: uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

I used the Magento 2 plugin in PhpStorm to create an entity with grid and form. It seems to work great until I renamed the fieldset name to “foo” and added tabs.

I already looked up many related posts/questions and did some digging in de vendor folder. But I can't seem to find it, the data simply won't fill the input fields unless the fieldset name is general. here is a code snippet of my form: `app/code/Vendor/SalesPromotion/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_promotion_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_promotion_form.sales_promotion_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sales_promotion_form.sales_promotion_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">sales_promotion_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sales Promotion Form</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <layout>
            <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
            <type>tabs</type>
        </layout>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Vendor\SalesPromotion\Block\Form\SalesPromotion\Save"/>
            <button name="back" class="Vendor\SalesPromotion\Block\Form\SalesPromotion\Back"/>
            <button name="delete" class="Vendor\SalesPromotion\Block\Form\SalesPromotion\Delete"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="sales_promotion_form_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/provider">
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="sales_promotion/salespromotion/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\SalesPromotion\Ui\DataProvider\SalesPromotionDataProvider" name="sales_promotion_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>sales_promotion_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>sales_promotion_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="foo" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">General</label>
            <dataScope/>
        </settings>
        <field name="sales_promotion_id" sortOrder="0" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_promotion_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Entity ID</label>
                <dataScope>sales_promotion_id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="name" sortOrder="00" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="bar" sortOrder="20">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Conditions</label>
            <dataScope/>
        </settings>
        <field name="min_cart_total" sortOrder="80" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">min_cart_total</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>float</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Min Cart Total</label>
                <dataScope>min_cart_total</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="howdy" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Email</label>
            <dataScope/>
        </settings>
        <field name="email_template" sortOrder="110" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">email_template</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Email Template</label>
                <dataScope>email_template</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more debugging, and finding this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/311982/73528 . I came to the idea to look around in the `vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form.php` file here we see the following:

```
public function getDataSourceData()
{
    $dataSource = [];
    $id = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam($this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getRequestFieldName(), null);
    $idFieldName = $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getPrimaryFieldName();
    $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField($idFieldName)
        ->setValue($id)
        ->create();
    $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()
        ->addFilter($filter);

    $data = $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getData();

    if (isset($data[$id])) {
        $dataSource = [
            'data' => $data[$id]
        ];
    } elseif (isset($data['items'])) {
        foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
            if ($item[$idFieldName] == $id) {
                $dataSource = ['data' => ['general' => $item]];
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

so this means if it can't find the array key similar to the id of the entity it will dump all data into the general field. And it does seem to ignore the  in the fieldsets. So as a solution I added the id in my "loadedData" in my dataprovider:

```
    /**
     * Get data.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData(): array
    {
        if ($this->loadedData) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }

        $this->loadedData = parent::getData();
        $itemsById = [];

        foreach ($this->loadedData['items'] as $item) {
            $itemsById[(int)$item[SalesPromotionInterface::SALES_PROMOTION_ID]] = $item;
        }

        if ($id = $this->request->getParam(SalesPromotionInterface::SALES_PROMOTION_ID)) {
            $this->loadedData['entity'] = $itemsById[(int)$id];
            $this->loadedData[$id] = $itemsById[(int)$id]; /// this line was added
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
```

But! That's not all we also have to add the datascope to data in our ui_component form as following:

```
    <fieldset name="howdy" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Email</label>
            <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        </settings>
```

and now finally we see the data.

Answer (score 2):

*Addition to the correct answer from [@ThatOneGuyThatDontGetIt](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/73528/thatoneguythatdontgetit)* :

---

Another way to lead all fields to correct data source is to **set `dataScope` of the form as `data.general` globally**, as in example:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <dataScope>data.general</dataScope>
```

After that, you no longer need to specify the correct scope on each filed, all data will be automatically linked with `${ $.provider }:data.general`