# Product edit page move tabs to sidebar

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml

In the default layout for the admin product edit page, we have an **accordion style** setup. This is really annoying as you have to scroll down several pages every time you want to edit an option that's not part of the **General tab**.

I would like to have a sidebar like on the customer edit page. Switching to **"admin-2columns-left"** doesn't seem to do the trick. Is there any recommended way of achieving this?

I'm using the default Magento admin theme. Not Luma. Luma is a frontend theme. I don't think the default admin theme has a name.

I'm talking about

```
vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend
```

Comment: hi have you done this?

Comment: Nope, couldn't find a straight forward and future proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

For add Tab structure in admin form instead of collapsible structure, you have to need customization `catalog_product_edit.xml` and `product_form.xml`. also, need more customization relevant to tab structure.

To display Tab structure in admin product form you need to remove first collapsible structure argument `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>` and add `<navContainerName>left</navContainerName>` under lyout arguments. like below.

> ui_component/product_form.xml

Remove this code `<item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>` from line number approx **16**

Find and replace below code with existing code.

```
<settings>
    <reloadItem>product-details.attribute_set_id:value</reloadItem>
    <buttons>
        <button name="save" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Save"/>
        <button name="addAttribute" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\AddAttribute"/>
        <button name="back" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Back"/>
    </buttons>
    <layout>
        <navContainerName>left</navContainerName>
        <type>tabs</type>
    </layout>
    <deps>
        <dep>product_form.product_form_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
```

Then follow the column structure [How to add tab structure in admin ui-component form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249135/magento-2-2-6-how-to-add-tab-structure-in-admin-ui-component-form)

> catalog_product_edit.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="admin-2columns-left">        
</page>
```

Change above code with existing code.

You may get below error :

> Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery::isAjaxLoaded

**Note :** In the above code explanation I am sharing just idea how can you achieve these things. you have customization as per your need. Make sure do not change any code file. you have to override core file and go ahead.

Take reference from below link

- [magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208308](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208308/how-to-add-tab-in-form-ui-component)
- [community.magento.com](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Add-nav-or-tab-to-Adminhtml-Ui-Custom-module-form/m-p/73279/highlight/false#M1656)
- [webkul.com/blog](https://webkul.com/blog/tab-with-form-in-admin-customer-edit-magento-2-0/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. After making the suggested changes the product edit page doesn't load anymore. I get the error: `Invalid method Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery::canShowTab`