# Magento2.3.4 - Create pop up admin form like add/edit customer address in admin

Tags: magento2, adminform, popup

I'm using `Magento2.3.4` and I want to show a grid in tab content , and  then I can edit the record with pop up form just like the customer edit address in admin

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Here is your solution for 
creating a **tab** https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208308/how-to-add-tab-in-form-ui-component